# When a single Ajax on success callback is done continue with the other from a jQuery when function?

Tags: php, jquery, python, ajax, web-crawler

Is there a way to call the next Ajax inside a jquery "when" function when the one called is completed (could be a call back or something?).
So far I put this example also in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HMLMR/)

Array of urls in this example for a localhost crawler

```
var iterations = ['//localhost?p=1', '//localhost?p=2', '//localhost?p=3'];
```

Will hold every ajax call

```
var xhr = [];
```

Do the iteration

```
$.each(iterations, function(url, k){

    // store every ajax function in the array
    xhr.push(
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            //async: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: onSuccess
        })
    );
})

    // then must be called when all onSuccess functions are done completed (every onsuccess have their own ajax call as well)
    $.when.apply($, xhr).then(function(){
        alert('This must be called when all xhrs have been triggered');
    })
```

When the AJAX call inside this function has been triggered continue with the next xhr iteration. is there a way to put a callback on the onSuccess function?

```
function onSuccess(data){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost',
                cache: false,
                //async: false,
                dataType: "html",
            success: function(){
                alert("on success 2, continue with the next xhr iteration");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("on error 2, continue with the next xhr iteration");

            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

1. Setup a queue using an array of "requests" (I see you already have that).
2. Then start the queue by executing the first request.
3. On the callback of that first request, move your iterator onto the second request, and start it (could be just a simple int that starts at 0 and that you increment every time). The callback of that second request is the same as the first one.
4. When your iterator reaches the end of the array, all your requests are complete, you can call your final method.

With this method, only one request is running at a time. If you want them all at the same time, then you need another array to track the status of each request. Every time a request completes, check your status array to see if they are all complete by looping through it.

Answer (score 1):

A good option would be to make a class or function to handle this kind of processing.  You could do this a couple of ways.  Let's say you do this with a utility class... I could imagine it having a constructor, `start()`, and `_next()`.

The constructor would take in and save an array of URLs.

The `start()` would fire an AJAX request with its success (and maybe error) callback to `_next()`.

`_next()` would look at the array of urls, and pick the next one (this could be done by shifting them off of the array or using and internal pointer/head; then `_next()` would make another AJAX call using `_next()` again as the success/error callback.

Lastly, there would need to be a terminating case in `_next()` for when there were no more URLs to call.